# How to resolve conflicts with git merge without committing unwanted files?

Tags: git, merge, meld

I have a problem resolving a conflict with git merge. When I tried the command `git merge branch_1` a conflict with a file appeared. I was able to succesfully resolve it using `git mergetool` with Meld. The problem is, after I have done it, I tried again to merge but it says that I have to commit my changes to conclude the merge. So before doing that I checked the `git status` and I found that there is a bunch of files in the staging area that I haven't modified. I guess those files where brought by the failed merge, but now how am I supposed to finish the merge without committing those files? Thanks!

Comment: Not adding an answer because the existing answers have all the technical info and next steps; but just want to add a note about where I think your thinking has gone wrong, as it might help with understanding those answers. Resolving conflicts (when necessary) is a step in completing a merge. You're thinking of it like "I resolve the conflicts, then I again try to merge"; but that's not right. If you did that, you would be back at square one and have to resolve the conflicts again.  A merge stages and then commits a new version of the code; in case of conflict, git lets you help with staging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a problem resolving a conflict with git merge. When I tried the command `git merge branch_1` a conflict with a file appeared.

This is normal enough.  Remember that `git merge branch_1` means:

1. Identify the current commit (the tip of the current branch).  I call this *L* for Left or Local or `--ours` (I know `l` does not appear in `ours`...).
2. Identify one other commit (the tip of `branch_1`).  I call this *R* for Right or Remote or otheR or `--theirs`.
3. Find, automatically, a *third* commit.  This third commit is the *merge base* and it's the point where the two branches first come back together:

   ```
                o--L   <-- current_branch (HEAD)
               /
   ...--o--o--B
               \
                o--R   <-- branch_1
   ```

   Commit *B* here is the merge base commit.
4. Make two diffs.  One finds out what *we* changed since the merge base:

   ```
   git diff --find-renames B L   # what we did
   ```

   and the other finds out what *they* changed since the merge base:

   ```
   git diff --find-renames B R   # what they did
   ```
5. *Combine* the two change-sets found with the two `git diff` commands.  Take one copy of each change to each file.  Build up, for committing, a new set of files that are like what was in *B*, except that each line of each file that we changed in *B-vs-L* is changed, and each line of each file that they changed in *B-vs-R* is also changed.
6. If none of these changes conflict, commit the result.  Otherwise, stop and complain about the conflicting changes.  Leave, ready to be committed, the non-conflicting files.  Leave the conflicted files in conflicted state, ready for manual merging or merging using some sort of merge tool.

> I was able to succesfully resolve it using `git mergetool` with Meld.

What `git mergetool` does is find the files left unmerged in step 6.  In your case there was just one such file.  Then `git mergetool` runs the tool on each such file, and if the tool claims that you have successfully resolved the conflict, `git mergetool` will add the file to the set of files ready to commit, thus resolving the conflict.

> [Git] says that I have to commit my changes to conclude the merge. So before doing that I checked the git status and I found that there is a bunch of files in the staging area that I haven't modified. I guess those files where brought by the failed merge,

Those files were, in fact, *successfully merged*.  (Well, at least Git thinks so.  You might want to verify that what Git thinks is good, is really good, because Git is not very smart. :-) )  Note that `git diff --cached` will compare what's in the index, ready to be commited, vs what's in the current tip of the current branch.

> but now how am I supposed to finish the merge without committing those files?

Normally you *would* want to include those staged, ready-to-commit changes in the files you're committing: they came from the *B-vs-R* changeset, and normally you should keep them.

If you really *shouldn't* keep them, note that you can do anything you like to what's in the work-tree, and then `git add` the modified files to copy them into the index/staging-area so that whatever *else* you have done is *also* (or instead) included.  You can even extract the version of any file that appears in any other commit, including the tip of your current branch.

Whatever you put into the index/staging-area *will be* in the next commit.  That's the definition of the index/staging-area.  (Note that it doesn't hold *changes*, it holds *files*—copies of specific files.  It's the act of comparing, with `git diff`, that shows you changes.  Running `git status` is really running `git diff`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `git commit` to finish the merge.

When you hit a merge conflict, git stages everything what it was able to merge. Files with merge conflicts are NOT staged and must be handled manually. `git status` will tell you what files are affected.

You can use `git mergetool` - this will usually stage your (hopefully) resolved changes on exit. You usually get a *.orig file for each resolved conflict file. This one just tells you what the original file looked like. Obviously, you don't want to commit these files...

Alternative, if you don't like the mergetool and want to fix it by hand, you can just edit them in your preferred editor. Conflicts, resolved via your editor, must be flagged as resolved via `git add path/to/conflicting/file`, to make git aware you have resolved the conflict.

Finally, run `git commit` for finishing the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn’t support committing your conflict resolutions in a separate commit, because those changes don’t make sense except within a merge commit. It wouldn’t make sense to commit it on top of one of the two branches that are being merged, because the resolutions change code that were from the other branch, and it wouldn’t make sense to commit it on top of the merge commit, because the merge commit would contain conflicts, which would make it an invalid commit.

You should just run `git merge --continue` (or, equivalently, `git commit`) to create a single merge commit containing the modifications to the files from both branches plus the modifications you did while resolving conflicts.